# Want to hide bottom sheet behind keyboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

In a scaffold, there is bottom sheet and text field. Want to hide bottom sheet with keyboard when focus on text field and keyboard appear. Use bottom sheet because of `product name` is a dynamic list and can scroll. How can I hide bottom sheet or is there any way?

[image]

[image]

here is my code frame

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return return Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            bottomSheet: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: mainColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(16),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(16),
                ),
              ),
              child: Container(
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 2, end: 2, top: 2),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(14),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(14),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 5, right: 12),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    height: ScreenSizeConfig.screenHeight,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            ));;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to bottom sheet

```
isScrollControlled = false;
```

Comment: I want to show always **Total** bottom sheet and ```showModalBottomSheet``` need action to appear. As alternative, I want to use a child of ```bottomSheet``` of ```Scaffold```.

Comment: I didnt get you. Can you explain a little more please

Comment: I mean **Total** text Container is inside ```bottomSheet``` of the ```Scaffold``` widget. When I focus the text field keyboard appear and the **Total** also move upward over keyboard as shown in pic. I don't want that. I only want that **Total** box to cover with keyboard, want to still bottom although keyboard appear.
The reason of that I use ```bottomSheet``` is upper widget is scroll widget.

Comment: I checked the code and its working as expected. can you add the full code here please

Comment: Now... I already fixed it. I used that **Total** container widget inside ```Column```widget instead of ```bottomSheet``` . Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i'm used _sheetController:

```
  late PersistentBottomSheetController _sheetController;

  bool bottomSheetEnabled = false;

  void _showBottomSheet(BuildContext context, Widget content) {
    bottomSheetEnabled = true;
    _sheetController = Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      (context) {
        // return Content();
        return content;
      },
    )..closed.whenComplete(() {
        print('*** closed');
      });
  }

  void _hideBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    if (bottomSheetEnabled) {
      _sheetController.close();
      bottomSheetEnabled = false;
    }
  }
```

when we need to open i'm use:

```
                    _showBottomSheet(
                      context,
                      const CustomBottomSheet(),
                    );
```

if close:

```
                   _hideBottomSheet(context);
```

Comment: May be true. Thanks for answering. But I don't currently do that now. So can't test for now.